# Laravel 6.0 php artisan route:list returns “Target class [App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController] does not exist.”

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 6.0 and I try to list all my routes with `artisan route:list`, but it fails and returns:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target
> class [App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController] does not exist.
>
> at /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:806
> 802|
> 803|         try {
> 804|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
> 805|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
> > 806|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
> 807|         }
> 808|
> 809|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
> 810|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
> [internal]:0
>
> 2   ReflectionException::("Class App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController does not exist")
> /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:804
>
> 3   ReflectionClass::__construct("App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController")
> /home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:804

Up to now I just have a very simple web.php routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});


Route::prefix('app')->group(function () {
    // Registration routes
    Route::get('registration/create', 'RegistrationController@create')->name('app-registration-form');
});


// Templates
Route::get('templates/ubold/{any}', 'UboldController@index');
```

Any idea how I could debug this issue?

Comment: Did you make sure to run php artisan config:cache?

Comment: Do you have any SessionsController?

Comment: Shame on me. I thought I created the SessionsController, but I didn't. After creating it and running php artisan config:cache it works. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: It could also be the namespace at the top of your controller

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Run this command

```
  php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 74):

I was upgrading from Laravel 7 to **Laravel 8** (Laravel 8 is still a few days in development) and also had this issue.

The solution was to use a classname representation of the controller in the route:

So in **web.php** instead of

```
Route::get('registration/create', 'RegistrationController@create')
```

it is now:

## Solution 1: Classname representation

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController;

Route::get('/', [RegistrationController::class, 'create']);
```

## Solution 2: String syntax

or as a string syntax (full namespaces controller name):

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController@create');
```

## Solution 3: Return to previous behaviour

As this should issue should only happen if you upgrade your application by creating a brand new laravel project you can also just **add the default namespace to the RouteServiceProvider**:

**app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /* ... */
     
    /** ADD THIS PROPERTY
     * If specified, this namespace is automatically applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace) // <-- ADD THIS
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace) // <-- ADD THIS
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
        });
    }

    /* ... /*
}
```

See also https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing or https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade (search for "Routing").

Comment: just ran into this! Wish docs were updated + they wouldn't change little things like this. annoying.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, and removing one syntax support entirely break the entire project, right? They could've integrated both in.

Comment: in addition to this change, the default namespace is null now. Adding the namespace and you don't have to specify every controller with a use statement:
_namespace App\Http\Controllers;_

Comment: Something like this works to

Route::group(["namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers\Web"], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Website@home');
});

Answer (score 39):

For those who have similar issue with `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException : Target class [<className>] does not exist.` message, this also could be helpful:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was solved by running

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

The `optimize:clear`commands clears everything

Comment: This doesn't  work on my error message, Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [MessagesController] does not exist., thanks to you anyway

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was a matter of Linux's file name case sensitivity. For a file named `IndexController`, having `Indexcontroller` will work in windows but not in Linux

Answer (score 5):

Simply add the following line in `app->Providers->RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It was commented out in my new Laravel project, so I uncommented it and all's well.

Comment: Where exactly should I add those codes?

Comment: You can add between the curly braces of RouteServiceProvider class

Answer (score 3):

In my case same `error` occurred because of forward slash `/` but it should be backward slash `\` in defining route,

it happens when you have controller in `folder` like as in my case controller was in `api` Folder, so always use backward slash `\` while mentioning controller name.

see example:

**Error-prone code:**

```
Route::apiResource('categories', 'api/CategoryController');
```

### **Solution code:**

```
Route::apiResource('categories', 'api\CategoryController');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect answer, I think:

- Option 1:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomepageController;
Route::get('/', [HomepageController::class, 'index']);
```

- Option 2:

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomepageController@index');
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright i got similar problem, i was trying to be smart so i wrote this in my web.php

```
Route::group([
    'middleware'    => '', // Removing this made everything work
    'as'            => 'admin.',
    'prefix'        => 'admin',
    'namespace'     => 'Admin',
],function(){

});
```

All i had to do is just to remove all the unnecessary/unused option from group. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

try to correct your controller name

my route was

```
Route::get('/lien/{id}','liensControler@show');
```

and my controller was

```
class liensController extends Controller
{
  // all the methods of controller goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did all these

1: php artisan config:cache

2: checked for controller name spellings.

3: composer dump-autoload

4: Just changed the forward / slash to backward \ in route.

4th one worked for me.

Comment: This solution doesn't work on my error, thanks to you for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Now You Can use controller outside controller folder

```
use App\Http\submit;

Route::get('/', [submit::class, 'index']);
```

Now my controller excited in http folder

You have to change in controller file something

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class submit extends Controller {
    public function index(Request $req) {
        return $req;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a route to this controller action like so:

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('user/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show']);

Answer (score 2):

I am running Laravel 8.x on my pc.
This error gave me headache. To recreate the error, this is what I did:
First I created a controller called MyModelController.php
Secondly, I wrote a simple function to return a blade file containing 'Hello World', called myFunction.
Lastly, I created a Route:
Route::get('/','MyModelController@myFunction');
This did not work.

This was how I solved it.
First you would have to read the documentation on:
(https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#laravel-8)

At the 'web.php' file this was the Route i wrote to make it work:

use App\Http\Controllers\MyModelController;

Route::get('/', [MyModelController::class, 'myFunction']);

Comment: The question specify Laravel version 6 where the provided semantic work properly.

Comment: Actually,  I am also using Laravel 8 and his answer worked for me. and he clearly stated that his solution is for Laravel 8.x

Comment: I had a similar problem with Laravel 8. Turns out I didn't include the controller at the top of the routes page (web.php): `use App\Http\Controllers\NameOfController;`

Answer (score 2):

on Larave 7 I had the same issue.

I checked the spelling of the controller name.

I recognize I have the wrong spelling in the "AlbumContoller" and I rename it to "AlbumController". so I forgot "r"

after I renamed the file and controller name and controller name in the web.php

```
Route::resource('albums', 'AlbumsController');
```

everything worked well

So You Don't need these two:

1- use App\Http\Controllers\IndexContoller;

2- Route::get('/', [MyModelController::class, 'myFunction']);

Comment: This worked for me, i've put 'BannerController' between quotation marks

Answer (score 2):

you have to specify full path to the class

Previously it was

```
Route::get('/wel','Welcome@index');
```

Now it has changed to

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Welcome;
Route::get('wel',[Welcome::class,'index']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while leaving an empty middleware class in my middleware groups by mistake :

```
    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:100,1',
            'bindings',
            'localization',
            '' // Was empty by mistake
        ],
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

replace-

```
Route::resource('/admin/UserOff','admin/UsersController');
```

with-

```
Route::resource('/admin/UserOff','admin\UsersController');
```

forward / with \

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with a middleware controller. So finally I linked that middleware in kerner.php file. It is located at **app\Http\Kernel.php**

I have added this line in route middleware.
**'authpostmanweb' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthPostmanWeb::class**

```
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'authpostmanweb' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthPostmanWeb::class
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of ensuring that you use the updated route syntax:

```
Route::get('/', [RegistrationController::class, 'create']);
```

make sure that at the top of your routes/web.php the controller is included in the name space like:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController;
```

Answer (score 0):

just check web.php and see lower and upper case letters