# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\OrderController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error "Target class [App\Http\Controllers\OrderController] does not exist." when ever i run "**php artisan route:list** and I can't determine what or where is the problem in this code or I am just Dumb tho

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Order;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(Order::with(['product'])->get(),200);
    }

    public function deliverOrder(Order $order)
    {
        $order->is_delivered = true;
        $status = $order->save();

        return response()->json([
            'status'    => $status,
            'data'      => $order,
            'message'   => $status ? 'Order Delivered!' : 'Error Delivering Order'
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $order = Order::create([
            'product_id' => $request->product_id,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'address' => $request->address
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => (bool) $order,
            'data'   => $order,
            'message' => $order ? 'Order Created!' : 'Error Creating Order'
        ]);
    }

    public function show(Order $order)
    {
        return response()->json($order,200);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Order $order)
    {
        $status = $order->update(
            $request->only(['quantity'])
        );

        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $status ? 'Order Updated!' : 'Error Updating Order'
        ]);
    }

    public function destroy(Order $order)
    {
        $status = $order->delete();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => $status,
            'message' => $status ? 'Order Deleted!' : 'Error Deleting Order'
        ]);
    }
}
```

here is my code from my order controller please help me and Thank you in advance for helping me

Comment: please put your web.php.

Comment: Is the controller surely in correct folder? Sometimes if you manually rename / move files, things gets mixed up. This shouldn't cause that error, but you might want also to `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` in `OrderController`.

Comment: try this command always after changing config files `php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

run below command

```
  php artisan config:cache
```

or

```
 composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

after you ensue no spelling problem between controller and route, try one of these possible solutions:

1. run `php artisan config:cache`
2. run `composer dump-autoload`
3. check your web.php routes and change the forward `/` slash to backward `\`

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865517/laravel-6-0-php-artisan-routelist-returns-target-class-app-http-controllers-s) it will help

Answer (score 0):

First check your directory your controller is in seperate folder in controler folder or it is in controller folder. If your Controller file is in new folder like Controller/YourFolder/Your file the you use in web.php route like below

```
Route::get('your url','YourFOlderName\COntrolername@methodname')->name('your route 
name')
```

I hope its work fine

Comment: You really should use \ instead of / though

Answer (score 0):

check out the route. E.g. in my case I ve gotten similar error after setting the route  in **web.php** . It had been written wrong:

```
 Route::get('/dispatch_notes/{order_id}','order\AddNotesController.php@dispatchNotes')
  ->name('dispatch_notes');
```

Had its name  wrong  copypasted from controllers folder. After suggested playings with cache  clearings saw that and removed the `.php` off its name and got it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8

In RouteServiceProvider uncomment

```
protected $namespace='App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for me the problem was I did not import the OrderController in my web.php. so always check if the file you trying to access on the web.php is imported