# target class [App\Http\Controllers\auth\ResetCandidatePasswordController] does not exist. after deployment to nginx laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Hello all I have a controller called ResetCandidatePasswordController in /var/www/jtt/app/Http/Controllers/Auth /var/www/jtt/app/Http/Controllers/Auth with the following code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Phone;
use  App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class ResetCandidatePasswordController extends Controller
{ //functions
```

The web.php route file:

```
Route::get('/candidate/requestreset', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetCandidatePasswordController::class, 'showform']);
Route::post('/candidate/reset', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetCandidatePasswordController::class, 'reset']);
```

Everythin worked fine on xampp local server. But after deployment I se this error.
Also I will post a nginx'es config file for this site, please consider this if it can help.

/etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name jtt.dp.ua;
    return 301 https://jtt.dp.ua;
}



server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 256M;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;


    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jtt.dp.ua/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jtt.dp.ua/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot


    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    server_name jtt.dp.ua www.jtt.dp.ua;
    root        /var/www/jtt/public;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;


    access_log  /tmp/access.log;
    error_log   /tmp/error.log;

    location  / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/pki-validation/ {
        allow all;
        default_type "text/plain";
    }

    
}
```

And here is what in logs. Don't mind the public/candidate folder.

```
2021/02/11 13:05:40 [error] 326#326: *654 access forbidden by rule, client: 20.81.218.11, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/11 22:23:19 [error] 326#326: *704 directory index of "/var/www/jtt/public/js/" is forbidden, client: 51.15.191.81, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/11 22:26:06 [error] 326#326: *705 directory index of "/var/www/jtt/public/js/" is forbidden, client: 62.4.14.206, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/11 22:32:06 [error] 326#326: *707 directory index of "/var/www/jtt/public/css/" is forbidden, client: 62.4.14.198, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /css/ HTTP/1.1", host: "jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/11 22:54:19 [error] 326#326: *719 directory index of "/var/www/jtt/public/css/" is forbidden, client: 62.4.14.198, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /css/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/12 11:03:36 [error] 326#326: *1182 access forbidden by rule, client: 178.128.194.144, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/14 06:09:15 [error] 326#326: *1575 access forbidden by rule, client: 194.33.45.246, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/14 10:31:20 [error] 326#326: *1622 access forbidden by rule, client: 94.102.49.193, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.well-known/security.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/14 14:35:17 [error] 326#326: *1674 access forbidden by rule, client: 185.163.109.66, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.well-known/security.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/15 03:26:07 [error] 326#326: *1744 access forbidden by rule, client: 31.220.2.222, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/15 03:26:28 [error] 326#326: *1748 access forbidden by rule, client: 185.220.100.251, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "www.jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/15 09:17:50 [error] 326#326: *1787 access forbidden by rule, client: 51.77.68.96, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/15 09:26:46 [error] 326#326: *1794 access forbidden by rule, client: 51.77.68.96, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/15 16:58:56 [error] 326#326: *2019 access forbidden by rule, client: 40.121.106.191, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/19 18:04:22 [error] 326#326: *2762 access forbidden by rule, client: 157.230.143.29, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/20 23:09:34 [error] 326#326: *2949 access forbidden by rule, client: 34.72.107.141, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/21 15:46:14 [error] 326#326: *3445 access forbidden by rule, client: 34.72.107.141, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/23 02:41:39 [error] 326#326: *3689 access forbidden by rule, client: 93.174.95.106, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.well-known/security.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/24 06:52:56 [error] 326#326: *3938 access forbidden by rule, client: 20.194.27.155, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "212.109.196.142"
2021/02/26 06:21:05 [error] 26631#26631: *5 directory index of "/var/www/jtt/public/images/" is forbidden, client: 46.119.159.82, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /images/ HTTP/1.1", host: "jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/26 06:27:46 [error] 26631#26631: *18 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Util.class.php on line 2064" while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.119.159.82, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock:", host: "jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/27 10:23:03 [error] 25322#25322: *1 open() "/var/www/jtt/public/candidate/requestresetsec" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 46.119.159.82, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /candidate/requestresetsec HTTP/1.1", host: "jtt.dp.ua"
2021/02/27 10:23:26 [error] 25322#25322: *1 open() "/var/www/jtt/public/candidate" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 46.119.159.82, server: jtt.dp.ua, request: "GET /candidate HTTP/1.1", host: "jtt.dp.ua"
```

Also I have noticed that even if I create a new controller with echoing somethin and root for it in web.php I am getting 404 on that newly created route. But other controllers are working just fine.
Maybe this will help. /var/www/jtt/storage/logs

```
[2021-02-27 15:51:25] local.ERROR: Target class [App\Http\Controllers\auth\ResetpasscandidateController] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Http\\Controllers\\auth\\ResetpasscandidateController] does not exist. at /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:832)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#1 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#2 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#3 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#4 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(268): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#5 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(989): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->getController()
#6 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(950): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->controllerMiddleware()
#7 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(709): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->gatherMiddleware()
#8 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware()
#9 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(669): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#10 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#11 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#12 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#16 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#18 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#19 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#20 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#22 /var/www/jtt/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#23 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#24 /var/www/jtt/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#26 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#28 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#29 /var/www/jtt/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#30 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"App\\Http\\Controllers\\auth\\ResetpasscandidateController\" does not exist at /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:830)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(830): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(712): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#2 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#3 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#4 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#5 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(268): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#6 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(989): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->getController()
#7 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(950): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->controllerMiddleware()
#8 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(709): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->gatherMiddleware()
#9 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware()
#10 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(669): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#11 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#12 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#13 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#17 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#19 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#21 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#23 /var/www/jtt/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#25 /var/www/jtt/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#27 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#29 /var/www/jtt/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#30 /var/www/jtt/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#31 {main}
"}
```

And also will add nginx error log. But have no idea how it can help

```
2021/02/27 07:14:02 [alert] 1158#1158: *589 open socket #14 left in connection 7
2021/02/27 07:14:02 [alert] 1158#1158: aborting
2021/02/27 10:18:58 [alert] 22519#22519: *254 open socket #15 left in connection 12
2021/02/27 10:18:58 [alert] 22519#22519: aborting
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you tried running composer autoload ?

try runnig

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Yes. I did. Result is the same.

Comment: Can you share what is written in error_log   /tmp/error.log; ?
also  auth  a is written with small letters maybe it should be written with capital A, Auth

[App\Http\Controllers\auth\ResetCandidatePasswordController]

[App\Http\Controllers\auth\ResetCandidatePasswordController]

Comment: Problem is that absolutly nothin

Comment: An other problem is that I wrote it everywhere with capital

Comment: Besides your question title... 
Could you share the error log ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=access+forbidden+by+rule

Allowing your directories might solve the problem I think

Comment: Do you mean somethin like add 777 rights to app/http/controllers/auth?

Comment: As for now in /var/www/jtt/app/Http/Controllers/Auth rights are 755

Comment: https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/11956
Here is one related conversation please check

Comment: Also you can try runnig

`php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload`

Here is one related conversation too :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865517/laravel-6-0-php-artisan-routelist-returns-target-class-app-http-controllers-s

Comment: Thank you very very much. As for now I commented out in nginx config all with deny and tryfiles 404. I know it is rather bad idea. Will continue on configuring nginx. Also clear cashe helped. I have seen those commands before but with artisan optimaze etc. Now I just simply cleared the cashe without any forther actions. So problem is solved.